# Why should I need backgoundColor when I draw lines on UIVew?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, draw, quartz-2d

I have some code like below:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    [self drawWithBezierPath];
    //[self drawOnCurrentGraphicsContext];
}

- (void)drawWithBezierPath
{
    if (self.selectedButtons.count > 0) {
        UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

        for (int i = 0; i < self.selectedButtons.count; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                UIButton *firstButton = [self.selectedButtons objectAtIndex:0];
                [bezierPath moveToPoint:firstButton.center];
            } else {
                UIButton *button = [self.selectedButtons objectAtIndex:i];
                [bezierPath addLineToPoint:button.center];
                [bezierPath moveToPoint:button.center];
            }
        }

        [bezierPath addLineToPoint:self.currentPoint];

        [bezierPath setLineWidth:5.0f];
        [bezierPath setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinRound];
        [[UIColor yellowColor] setStroke];

        [bezierPath stroke];
    }
}
```

I want to draw lines when the finger moves:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [self onTouch:touch];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [self onTouch:touch];
}

- (void)onTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (touch) {
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
        self.currentPoint = point;

        UIButton *button = [self buttonContainsPoint:point];
        if (button && ![self.selectedButtons containsObject:button]) {
            [self.selectedButtons addObject:button];
            button.selected = YES;
        }

        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

[image]

As the image above shows, When I move the finger, it draws many lines that I don't expect to.

I know I can do something like `CGContextClearRect` to clear lines drawn before, but the key thing I found is that, without `CGContextClearRect`, if I write `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`, then the lines drawn before will be cleared automatically.

[image]

So, if I don't set the background explicitly, the backgroundColor will be `nil`, and the iOS will not clear the lines drawn before, or it does but I don't know.

Could anybody tell me why? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess, changeing the background color will clear your drawings. Therefore you can use any color you want. If you will set the background color to red everything will be red and your lines will be cleared also.

Claus

Comment: Thanks @Claus, your guess is my guess too, so I could not accept your answer, but I just gave you an up-vote for your answer.